# "Title case the character in the given string as mentioned below"

Tags: python, string

You are given a string as an input: '1 w r 3g'

Expected output: '1 W R 3g'

Point to notice that 'g' character in the given output string must be in lowercase.

```
a = input()
b = list(a)
c = "".join(b)

c.title()
```

I have tried those line of code but getting '1 W R 3G' as an output instead of '1 W R 3g'** .**Once again to remind you that 'g' in the output string must be in lowercase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Once again to remind you that 'g' in the output string must be in lowercase." - **why**? What is the **rule that tells you** this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use title() - use capitalize() as follows:

```
s = '1 w r 3g'
print(*map(str.capitalize, s.split()))
```

**Output:**

```
1 W R 3g
```